# Android 4.2 getSupportFragmentManager().getMap() returns null

Tags: android, android-maps, supportmapfragment

I've met this problem on Android 4.2.
I have three devices, one has 4.1.1 on it, a two another have 4.2. On 4.1 phone getSupportFragmentManager().getMap() returns a map, I can see it, I can find my location and so on. But on two another it returns null.

Here's my code on map setup:

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
```

On 4.2 each of last three lines throws NullPointerException. On 4.1 all of them work.

I can't find, why it happens.

PS: Google maps works great on 4.2. And "My location" button works too.
PS2: In the settings "Access my location", "GPS Sattelites" and "Wi-Fi & mobile network location" are turned on.

Comment: Have you installed Google Play Services on devices?

Comment: Please visit to this link might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google now made a more convenient way to get the map using the following method

```
myMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback) {
     @Override
     public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
         myMap = googleMap;
         // Put your code here

     }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Check if Google Play Services is installed.
And may be you need to wait for some time before Map controller is inited.

```
mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {  
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GoogleMap map = getMap();
                if (map != null) {
                    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    // INIT HERE
                    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                    // ...

                } else mHandler.post(this);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've installed play services, and updated google apps. Now it works!